# Detox test: React native android app binary not found

Tags: android, react-native, testing, e2e-testing, detox

I am trying to test my react native app by using detox. I run detox build --configuration android.emu.debug successfully but when I run detox test --configuration android.emu.debug, I got an error :

Error: app binary not found at 'xxx/xxx/android/app/build/outputs/apk/androidTest/debug/app-debug.apk', did you build it?

I changed the path but it is not working. How can I solve this problem?

```
  "testRunner": "jest",
  "runnerConfig": "e2e/config.json",
  "configurations": {
    "ios": {
      "type": "ios.simulator",
      "binaryPath": "./ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/xxx.app",
      "build": "xcodebuild -workspace iOS/xxx.xcworkspace -scheme xxx -configuration Debug -sdk iphonesimulator -derivedDataPath ios/build",
      "device": {
        "type": "iPhone 11"
      }
    },
    "android.emu.debug": {
      "device": {
        "avdName": "Pixel_API_28_AOSP"
      },
      "type": "android.emulator",
      "binaryPath": "android/app/build/outputs/apk/androidTest/debug/app-debug.apk",
      "build": "cd android && ./gradlew assembleDebug assembleAndroidTest -DtestBuildType=debug && cd .."
    },
    "android.emu.release": {
      "device": "emulator",
      "type": "android.emulator",
      "app": "android.release"
    }
  }
}
```

It works on iOS

Comment: Your android binaryPath is wrong.it should be like this for android debug and release.             
  "binaryPath": "android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk"

Answer (score 1):

add this under binaryPath of android.emu.debug to override the test apk detox is currently looking at:

`"testBinaryPath":"android/app/build/outputs/apk/androidTest/debug/app-debug-androidTest.apk"`

or if your app-debug-androidTest.apk is somewhere else make sure to add the path of it as the value of testBinaryPath.

happy coding ^ ^.